# ajax call while updating page

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have an ajax call to one php script via jquery but it takes a lot of time to return results , So I would like to know how can I display results as its are being printed on my script. here just example of my php script:

```
<?php 
// process.php
for($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++){
echo json_encode(array("name" => $i) );
sleep(2); // this sleeps for 2 seconds
}
?>
```

Now with my jquery i am calling that page and have a form with id ajaxquery on page:

```
$("#ajaxquery").live( "submit" , function(){
    var formdata = $(this).serialize(); 
    $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: formdata,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data)
            {
                $("#success").html(data.name);
            }
        });

    return false; 
});
```

now this will output all results at same time after few seconds in div#success but how can i achieve it print that echo statements as soon process.php process it and then again wait 2 seconds and add next result in div success. thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to setup a javascript timer on the client and call you php script every two seconds to get the new data. That data you can append for example with the jquery `.append` function.

Comment: thank you sir but if i call again to process.php with javascript will not it rerun script from start again?

Comment: You will have to modify your script of cause to support that async pattern

Comment: thanks again, I was thinking what if i save that data to a result.txt file and then call javascript timer to check for new content and update from there and when ajax success is called i stop the timer, is that a proper way?

Comment: The problem with that way will be that is will work just for a single client or you have to maintain textfiles for every client that connects. Not talking about cleanup of that files...

Comment: well thanks, its actually only for a single client and one purpose so timer will work for me. Regards

Answer (score 0):

The success function is called only when the `$.ajax` function gets a successful response from the server and that happens only when the PHP script finishes it's execution. You must change your logic, for example by making another ajax call after the first one finishes that "resume" the work server side

Comment: thanks, I was thinking what if i save that data to a result.txt file and then call javascript timer to check for new content and update from there and when ajax success is called i stop the timer, is that a proper way?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, just wanted be sure if there was any better way :).. Regards